# Python: Indentation

Tags: python

I'm observing something weird in my code. In the following snipped, I have reduced long setting expressiongs to short place holders. Observe

```
import numpy as np
for t in np.arange(0,100):
    print "t", t
    # compute something
    e=1 
    for n in arange(0, 80):
        print "n", n
        if (df.loc[t, n]['d'] == 1):
            a=1
            b=2
            c=3
            d=4
            e=5 
        else:
            a=1
            b=2
            c=3
            d = 4 \
                + 5 \
                * 6
            e = 7
            e=8 * \
                9
        print t, n
```

So there is an outer loop over `t`, and an inner loop over `n`. The last `print t, n` is inside the inner loop - I would think - therefore it should be printed on every loop. My expected output is something along the lines of

```
t, 0
n, 0
0, 0
n, 1
0, 1
n, 2
0, 2
(..)
t, 1
```

However, the output is

```
t 0
n 0
n 1
n 2
n 3
n 4
n 5
n 6
n 7
n 8
n 9
n 10
n 11
n 12
n 13
n 14
n 15
n 16
n 17
n 18
n 19
n 20
n 21
n 22
n 23
n 24
n 25
n 26
n 27
n 28
n 29
n 30
n 31
n 32
n 33
n 34
n 35
n 36
n 37
n 38
n 39
n 40
n 41
n 42
n 43
n 44
n 45
n 46
n 47
n 48
n 49
n 50
n 51
n 52
n 53
n 54
n 55
n 56
n 57
n 58
n 59
n 60
n 61
n 62
n 63
n 64
n 65
n 66
n 67
n 68
n 69
n 70
n 71
n 72
n 73
n 74
n 75
n 76
n 77
n 78
n 79
t 1
1 79
```

Not only is `print t, n` not inside the inner loop, but also does not get called "at the end of the inner loop", but at the beginning of the second loop - with still the old inner loop variable `n = 79`. Please enlighten me what is going on here.

**Update**

So, running it from console went without problem. It is when I mark the code and set "run in console" in my IDE (PyCharm) that it breaks. I could narrow it down to a specific double liner:

```
            prof = (repo.profits(wNew, LTot, Grid.eGrid[df.loc[(t, n), 'a']], Param)
                -Param.psi * (Grid.lGridNoDefault[df.loc[(t, n), 'x']] - Param.delta) ** 2 / (LTot) * wNew )
```

What I didn't mention before: all this is inside a function. If I select code starting from the function definition up to (but excluding) the given line and set "run in terminal", the function gets defined. If I include this line, terminal tries to run it: It thinks the function definition ended in the previous line.

I tried to remove all the white space and "reindenting" with tabs as I do everywhere. Also, I tried to merge the two lines. Both attempts were fruitless - and I am clueless.

Comment: Try calling your script with the `-tt` option: `python -tt yourscript.py`.  This will cause mixed tabs and spaces to give an error.

Comment: also, you need to manually test `print t, n` and `np.arange()` to understand how they actually work.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. It seems indeed to be some issue related to Seth's comment. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the PyCharm Python console in how it handles multi line code. The same code copy & pasted ran in Canopy's iPython console.